# Get a picture for each album

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two table for gallery system :

```
gallery_cat(
  gallery_cat_id    PK,
  gallery_cat_name
)

gallery(
  gallery_id        PK,
  gallery_cat_id    FK,
  gallery_name,
  gallery_file_name,
  gallery_date
)
```

I need to write a SQL query that return one picture from gallery table for each album, the purpose of this that I need to list the albums with one picture for each.

```
gallery_name | gallery_cat_name| gallery_file_name
-------------+-----------------+------------------
pic1         | Album1          | pic1.jpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT g2.gallery_name, gc2.gallery_cat_name, g2.gallery_file_name
FROM gallery g2
INNER JOIN gallery_cat gc2 ON (g2.gallery_cat_id = gc2.gallery_cat_id)
WHERE g2.gallery_id IN (
  SELECT g.gallery_id     
  FROM gallery g
  GROUP BY g.gallery_cat_id)
```

Explanation:

At the end is a **sub-select**

```
IN (
  SELECT g.gallery_id     
  FROM gallery g
  GROUP BY g.gallery_cat_id) <<-- select 1 random g.id per gallery_cat.
```

Here I select all g.id, **but** because of the `group by` clause it will reduce the results to 1 row per grouped by item. I.e. 1 row (chosen more or less at random) per `g.gallery_cat_id`.

Next I do a normal select with a join:

```
SELECT g2.gallery_name, gc2.gallery_cat_name, g2.gallery_file_name
FROM gallery g2
INNER JOIN gallery_cat gc2 ON (g2.gallery_cat_id = gc2.gallery_cat_id)
WHERE g2.gallery_id IN (
```

Because I refer to the same table twice in the same query you have to use an alias(*).
I select all names and all catnames and all filenames.
However in the `where` clause I filter these so that only rows from the sub-select are shown.

I **have** to do it this way, because the group by mixes rows into one messed up ow, if I select from **that** directly I will get values from different rows mixed together, not a good thing.
By first selecting the id's I want and then matching full rows to those id I prevent this from happening.

**(in this case with this kind of subselect that's not really 100% true, but trust me on the point that it's always a good idea to alias your tables)*

Answer (score 1):

This attempts to select the most recent `gallery_date` for each category ID and join against `gallery_cat`

```
SELECT 
  c.gallery_cat_id, 
  c.gallery_cat_name, 
  i.lastimg
FROM
  gallery_cat c 
  LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT gallery_cat_id, gallery_filename AS lastimg, MAX(gallery_date)
   FROM gallery 
   GROUP BY gallery_cat_id, gallery_filename 
  ) i ON c.gallery_cat_id = i.gallery_cat_id
```

Comment: @shox Make it a `LEFT JOIN`. Edited above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SQL JOINS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) to do this, otherwise you would have to loop out all the albums and pick one random picture from each which would be less efficient.